System of probability equations?
I am somewhat new to probability and statistics, and I am trying to figure out how to solve a particular type of problem. I am not sure if it is very elementary or very difficult. If there is a general set of techniques for solving problems of this sort, I would appreciate it if someone could direct me to them.
Suppose that I have a collection of (in my case, discrete) random variables $X_1,...,X_n$, which need not have the same distribution or domain, but all have the same codomain (in my case $\mathbb{N}$), together with a set of equations
\begin{align*} P(f_1(X_1,...,X_n)\leq g_1(X_1,...,X_n)\text{ }&|\text{ }h_1(X_1,...,X_n)\leq j_1(X_1,...,X_n)) = c_1 \\ P(f_2(X_1,...,X_n)\leq g_2(X_1,...,X_n)\text{ }&|\text{ }h_2(X_1,...,X_n)\leq j_2(X_1,...,X_n)) = c_2 \\  &\;\;\vdots \\ P(f_m(X_1,...,X_n)\leq g_m(X_1,...,X_n)\text{ }&|\text{ }h_m(X_1,...,X_n)\leq j_m(X_1,...,X_n)) = c_m \end{align*}
such that each $f_i, g_i, h_i, j_i$ is linear. I want to be able to "solve" this system of equations, by which I mean that I want to determine the most probable value (or range of values) for each $X_i$, as well as obtain confidence intervals for such. Such a solution might not exist, of course, but if it does, how do I find it? If that is to much to ask, suppose that I already have known values for each $X_i$, and I simply want to put bounds on how likely this set of values is to occur given the equations above. In general I am just asking if there is an establish set of techniques for dealing with systems of equations of this sort.
Thanks!
